# Commerce kickstart select country and don't show product

Tags: commerce

I use commerce kickstat and I have some products on my site. I want to disable add to cart button when user is not form some country.. for example.. USA.. if user is from USA he can see add to cart.. other not

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to add a `hook_form_alter` and modify the commerce add to cart form to remove the button and/or change it up to your liking:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, 'cart_add_to_cart') === 0) {
    if (/* Insert your logic here */) {
      unset($form['submit']);
      $form['submit'] = array('#markup' => '<p class="not-available">Not available in your country</p>');
    }
  }
}
```